# Access Java Application with MySQL DB from LAN Computers

Tags: java, mysql, swing, user-interface

I made a desktop school management system application using java and mysql with netbeans. there are 3 GUIs as ADMIN GUI, TEACHER GUI and STUDENT GUI. now I want to do is, users can realtime access the GUIs from different computers. what I mean is, when admin is access the system from admin computer, as the same time a teacher can access the system from any other computer by the teacher GUI. here all computers are connected through LAN Network cable. how can I do this..? Please help. (Codes attached).

> **DB Connection Class(DBConnection.java):**

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public class DBConnection {
public static Connection dbconmethod() throws Exception{

    Connection c;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    c=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ssdb","root","250");

    return c;

 }
}
```

> **Login JFrame Code(Login.java):**

```
private void jBtn_LoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        if (txt_UserID.getText().equals("admin")&&txt_Password.getText().equals("123250")){
                new AdminHome().setVisible(true);
                AdminHome.txt_Log.setText(Login.txt_UserID.getText());
                this.dispose();

        }else if (txt_UserID.getText().equals("teacher")&&txt_Password.getText().equals("123250")){
                new TeacherHome().setVisible(true);
                TeacherHome.txt_Log.setText(Login.txt_UserID.getText());
                this.dispose();

        }else if (txt_UserID.getText().equals("student")&&txt_Password.getText().equals("123250")){
                new StudentHome().setVisible(true);
                StudentHome.txt_Log.setText(Login.txt_UserID.getText());
                this.dispose();

        }else{

        String uid = txt_UserID.getText();
        String pass = txt_Password.getText();
        String s1 = "";

        String sql = "SELECT status FROM admin_data WHERE user_id='"+uid+"' and password='"+pass+"' UNION SELECT user_role FROM tch_data WHERE user_id='"+uid+"' and password='"+pass+"' UNION SELECT user_role FROM stu_data WHERE user_id='"+uid+"' and password='"+pass+"'";

        try {
        java.sql.Connection c = DBConnection.dbconmethod();
        Statement s=c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= s.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()){   
                s1 = rs.getString(1);

                }if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Active")){
                        new  AdminHome().setVisible(true);
                        AdminHome.txt_Log.setText(Login.txt_UserID.getText());
                        this.dispose();

                }else if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("PRINCIPAL")||s1.equalsIgnoreCase("D.PRINCIPAL")||s1.equalsIgnoreCase("V.PRINCIPAL")||s1.equalsIgnoreCase("TEACHER")){
                        new  TeacherHome().setVisible(true);
                        TeacherHome.txt_Log.setText(Login.txt_UserID.getText());
                        this.dispose();

                }else if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase("STUDENT")){
                        new  StudentHome().setVisible(true);
                        StudentHome.txt_Log.setText(Login.txt_UserID.getText());
                        this.dispose();

                }else {
                        UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 22));
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "UserID or Password Incorrect, Re-check and try again!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        txt_UserID.setText(null);
                        txt_Password.setText(null);
                }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }    

}
```

Comment: what did you mean how i can do that?

Comment: Your problem isn't a GUI issue, mysql is a Database SERVER, it provides the capability of been accessed by multiple, remote clients simultaneously. You need to configure the database to allow external connections, which should be limited by the subnet so as to limit from where people can access the database for security.  A better solution might be to only allow local connections and provide a web service for remote clients to use, but that might beyond the scope of what you're trying to do. What you need to do, is goto the mysql documentation and read up on it's access configuration

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the IP of your server consider your database exist in another computer or server so you should to use the ip of that computer to create a Connection so instead to localhost you should to use the IP of that computer or server so you need to use :

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip_of_your_computer:3306/ssdb","root","250");
```

**Note**

You can use [Preprepd Statement doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of `Statement` it is more secure and more helpful because it can cause an SQL Injection you can read more about that here [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)